# getting nearest hidden field value on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get closest input type hidden value on button clicks in jquery . 
This is my html code

```
 <form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="carid">
        <input type="button" >  
    </form>
    <form  action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" id="carid">
        <input type="button" >         
    </form>
    <form  action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="3" id="carid">
        <input type="button" >       
    </form>
```

and nin jquery i have used on button click

```
var carid = $(this).closest('#carid').val();
```

I have used closest and sibling methods but dont know they work , any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var carid = $(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val();
```

Example :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
   
    alert($(this).parent().find("input[type='hidden']").val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="carid">
        <input type="button" >  
    </form>
    <form  action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" id="carid">
        <input type="button" >         
    </form>
    <form  action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" value="3" id="carid">
        <input type="button" >       
    </form>
```

Comment: giving undefined values